# Row-wise-sum in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:
Table1

```
Col1    Col2   Col3
1        A      10
2        B      20
3        C      30
4        D      40
5        E      50
```

I want output as follows:

Output :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Row-Wise-Sum
1       A       10      10
2       B       20      30
3       C       30      60
4       D       40      100
5       E       50      150
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want, just posting an example does not suffice.

Comment: He wants to sum the previous Col3,adding to the total.

Comment: And is there any auto increment id? If so, you could fetch prev rows sum and add up with the present one. Please elaborate the problem

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thanks for the link. I am looking for that solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is also known as a "running total" or "cumulative sum". If you search for any of those terms in combination with "SQL" you will find plenty of suggestions as to how this can be done.

Here's an answer that uses Window Functions in SQL Server 2012 or newer:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,
    SUM(Col3) OVER (ORDER BY Col1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [Row-Wise-Sum]
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY Col1
```

Comment: You should end the statement with ORDER BY Col1.

Answer (score 1):

Your talking a cumulative total

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, (SELECT SUM(Col3)
                       FROM Table1
                       WHERE Col1 <= Table1.Col1)
FROM   Table1
ORDER BY Table1.Col1;
```